# How to display value in Custom Listview from Edittext

Tags: java, android-listview, android-edittext

I have two EditText, I want to get edittext's value when I click button, and display that value in a custom layout. I included MainActivity.java and CustomAdapter.java and tried it many times in different ways but none of them worked.Please help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ed_text_1=credit_edt.getText().toString();
            String ed_text_2=gpa_edt.getText().toString();
            double d_value_1=Double.parseDouble(ed_text_1);
            double d_value_2=Double.parseDouble(ed_text_2);
            double result=d_value_1+d_value_2;

            CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,d_value_1,d_value_2,result);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            credit_edt.setText("");
            gpa_edt.setText("");
        }
    });
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

double str1;
double str2;
double ans;
Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context,double str1, double str2, double ans) {
    this.context = context;
    this.str1 = str1;
    this.str2 = str2;
    this.ans = ans;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.output_layout,parent,false);
    }
    TextView txt1=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crt_c_id);
    TextView txt2=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gp_c_id);
    TextView txt3=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tl_c_id);

    String s1=Double.toString(str1);
    String s2=Double.toString(str2);
    String s3=Double.toString(ans);

    txt1.setText(s1);
    txt2.setText(s2);
    txt3.setText(s3);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your custom adapter arguments

**Pass value from Activity**

```
 CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,d_value_1,d_value_2,result);
```

**And get it in to adapter**

```
 CustomAdapter(double[] str1, double[] str2, double[] ans, Context context)
```

**Check your argument datatype and sequence:-**
*From activity you pass context as a first argument and in adapter you get it in the last*

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thanks!!-But when i run this project and click button i can not see edittext value in layout..I update my CustomAdapter.java please see it and help.. @Arbaz.in

Comment: @Shihab007 why you are not use array list instated of passing the individual double values.

Comment: Give me some hint.I'm not understand how to implemet arraylist in customadapter. @Arbaz.in

Comment: please share your design so i can understand what you try to archive